# How to get the file name of image that I put into Dataloader in Pytorch or read the image from 0 to 100?

Tags: python, pytorch

I use PyTorch to load images like this:

```
inf_data = InfDataloader(img_folder=args.imgs_folder, target_size=args.img_size)
inf_dataloader = DataLoader(inf_data, batch_size=1, shuffle=False, num_workers=2)
```

And then:

```
with torch.no_grad():
    for batch_idx, (img_np, img_tor) in enumerate(inf_dataloader, start=1):
        img_tor = img_tor.to(device)
        pred_masks, _ = model(img_tor)
```

But my input folder is like
[image: example]

Windows read files like: 000,001,002.....100,101,102,....110,111....
As the system doesn't read my file from 0 to 10, it will misorder the output files' order.
For example, the input is 0.png. The output is 183.png.

One way is that I hope to read the image from 0.png or I want to get the file name in Dataloader.
I also have a question here.
[How to get the file name of image that I put into Dataloader in Pytorch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63529916/13716864)

Answer (score 0):

Besides the answer that I provide in https://stackoverflow.com/a/63537916/13716864

I sort the file name by:

```
self.imgs_folder = img_folder

self.img_paths = []

img_path = self.imgs_folder + '/'
img_list = os.listdir(img_path)
img_list.sort()
img_list.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[:-4]))  
img_nums = len(img_list)
for i in range(img_nums):
     img_name = img_path + img_list[i]
     self.img_paths.append(img_name)
```